# Build \ deploy - complex scenario and application

Tags: maven, deployment, ant, build, gradle

The managers grant our team with the task of creating an automated build \ deploy script for the production servers.

The script requirements are:

1. fetch latest release src code of web application from git.
2. compile - > WAR
3. connect to a remote server (production\test)
4. shutdown tomcat server on remote
5. execute schema updates on remote DB server (for new release)
6. deploy new war to tomcat and start it.

My questions are:

1. do all 3 major players in the build\deploy area can do that (ant \ maven \ gradle)?
2. is building a small application (java application) that does this exact steps is good practice ? (probably write a java app will be much faster than learning doing that in maven \ ant \ gradle)
3. are there any alternative tools for this kind of work?
4. are there any better alternatives for the whole "build-machine" idea?

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Do all 3 major players in the build/deploy area can do that (ant/maven/gradle)?

With enough customization of targets/goals, any of these can do what you want.

> Is building a small application (java application) that does this exact steps is good practice?

You certainly could (or just use a shell script), this is essentially the same thing as customizing the build tools listed prior.

> Are there any alternative tools for this kind of work?

My company has created [BuildMaster](http://inedo.com/buildmaster) specifically to solve these and additional problems related to deployment, and it sounds like the free version may suit your scenario.

The basic solution would be to:

1. Connect to Git by adding a Git source control provider (or if you're using GitHub, the GitHub provider)
2. Connect an agent to the target server and add it to BuildMaster (requires installation for Windows, but if deploying to Linux it just uses an SSH connection)
3. In your deployment plan, you'd use the following actions:

   1. "Build Ant Project" or "Execute Maven" to perform the actual build process
   2. "Create Build Artifact" to associate the build output (whether a WAR file or its contents) with the BuildMaster build
   3. "Stop Service" to stop Tomcat
   4. "Execute Database Scripts" to execute scripts on disk (whether you've pulled them from source or whatever) or "Execute Database Change Scripts" which works automatically if you've uploaded them to BuildMaster
   5. "Deploy Build Artifact" to deploy the previously captured artifact to the remote server
   6. "Start Service" Tomcat

What's neat about this approach is that when you create this deployment plan, it reads very similar to what is written out in the above steps.

Additional benefits that may or not pertain to your exact scenario that can be trivially added include:

- **Approvals & Signoff** - workflows can specify these to ensure QA signoffs occur before promotion
- **Release Management and Auditing** - know what build is in what environment and when it went there
- **Variable Deployments** - you can add branching logic to deployment plans to make it easy to select whether the "Debug" or "Release" build goes to test, for example.
- **Notifications** - users can subscribe to certain events (deployment, release, etc.) and receive email notifications when those events occur